# Using XmlSerializer deserialize complex type elements are null

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer, deserialization

I have the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tipos="http://www.ginfes.com.br/tipos_v03.xsd"  targetNamespace="http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_resposta_v03.xsd"
            xmlns="http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_resposta_v03.xsd" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xsd:import schemaLocation="tipos_v03.xsd" namespace="http://www.ginfes.com.br/tipos_v03.xsd" />
 <xsd:element name="ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="NumeroLote" type="tipos:tsNumeroLote" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     <xsd:element name="Situacao" type="tipos:tsSituacaoLoteRps" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="tipos:ListaMensagemRetorno" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and the following class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_envio_v03.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_envio_v03.xsd", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsEnvio
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public tcIdentificacaoPrestador Prestador { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public string Protocolo { get; set; }
}
```

Use the following code to deserialize the object:

```
XmlSerializer respSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta));
StringReader reader = new StringReader(resp);
ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta respModel = (ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta)respSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

does not occur any error but the properties of objects are null, anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you might just be ignoring the XML namespace and that might be your problem. In your XSD, you define a default XML namespace:

```
<xsd:schema 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:tipos="http://www.ginfes.com.br/tipos_v03.xsd"  
   targetNamespace="http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_resposta_v03.xsd"
   xmlns="http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_resposta_v03.xsd" 
   attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

See the `xmlns="http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_resposta_v03.xsd"` attribute? That defines a default XML namespace.

So when you go to deserialize your data, you should also supply that default XML namespace to the deserializer:

```
XmlSerializer respSerializer = new 
   XmlSerializer(typeof(ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta),
                 "http://www.ginfes.com.br/servico_consultar_situacao_lote_rps_resposta_v03.xsd");
StringReader reader = new StringReader(resp);
ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta respModel = 
  (ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta)respSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Does that work with the inclusion of the XML default namespace?

Comment: I have dominion over the schema, the XML only receive and process, I will try to remove the namespaces to see if it works.

 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta != ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsEnvio

You could have used easier names, it was hard to spot :)

You should also use XML validation (XmlReaderSettings supports setting it up) to instantly identify the problems. And at least make sure that the code was generated from the XSD directly, because there are mismatches here.

Comment: But he is trying to deserialize into a `ConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsResposta` type - I would say that **is** the one defined in the XML schema, no?

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. Anyway, it's a complete mess because he posted the schema for something else.